# Javascript Html5 canvas problems

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

This is a game I am making. I cant figure out why it is not working. I have the JS fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/aa68u/4/

```
    // Create the canvas
 var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 canvas.width = 512;
  canvas.height = 480;
 document.body.appendChild(canvas);



 // Background image
 var bgReady = false;
 var bgImage = new Image();
 bgImage.onload = function () {
     bgReady = true;
 };
 bgImage.src = "http://6269-9001.zippykid.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/Woods-Wallpaper.jpg";

 // Ship image
 var shipReady = false;
 var shipImage = new Image();
 shipImage.onload = function () {
     shipImage = true;
 };
 shipImage.src = "http://s29.postimg.org/3widtojzn/hero.png";

 // Astroid image
 var astroidReady = false;
 var astroidImage = new Image();
 astroidImage.onload = function () {
     astroidReady = true;
 };
 astroidImage.src = "http://s29.postimg.org/4r4xfprub/monster.png";

 // Game objects
 var ship = {
     speed: 256; 
 };
 var astroid = {};


 var health = 100;

 window.keyStates = {}; 

 addEventListener('keydown',  function (e) {
     keyStates[e.keyCode || e.key] = true;
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
 }, true);

 addEventListener('keyup',  function (e) {
      keyStates[e.keyCode || e.key] = false;
     e.preventDefault();
     e.stopPropagation();
 }, true);



 var reset = function () {

     astroid.width = 10;
     astroid.height = 10;
     astroid.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
     astroid.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));

     ship.speed = 256;

     for (var p in keyStates) keyStates[p]= false;
 };



 // Update game objects
 function update (modifier) {
     if (keyStates[38] ==true) { // Player holding up
         astroid.x -= ship.speed * modifier;
     }
     if (keyStates[40]==true) { // Player holding down
         astroid.x += ship.speed * modifier;
     }
     if (keyStates[37]==true) { // Player holding left
         astroid.y -= ship.speed * modifier;
     }
     if (keyStates[39]==true) { // Player holding right
         astroid.y += ship.speed * modifier;
     }
     if (astroid.width) < 200{
         astroid.width +=10;
         astroid.height += 10;
     }
     if (astroid.width) > 200{
         reset();
     }
     // Are they touching?
if (keyStates[32] == true && ship.x <= (astroid.x + 32) && astroid.x <= (ship.x + 32) && ship.y <= (astroid.y + 32) && astroid.y <= (ship.y + 32)) {
    monstersCaught += 1;
    reset();
}



 };


 // Draw everything
 var render = function () {
    if (bgReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0);
}



if (shipReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(heroImage, hero.x, hero.y);
}

if (astroidReady) {
    ctx.drawImage(monsterImage, monster.x, monster.y);
}

// Score
ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(250, 250, 250)";
ctx.font = "24px Helvetica";
ctx.textAlign = "left";
ctx.textBaseline = "top";
ctx.fillText("Your Health: " + health, 32, 32);

 };

 // The main game loop
 var main = function () {
var now = Date.now();
var delta = now - then;
if (delta > 20) delta = 20;

update(delta / 1000);
render();

then = now;
 };

 // Let's play this game!
 reset();
 var then = Date.now();
 setInterval(main, 1); // Execute as fast as possible
```

The game is supposed to be a ship(shoe image) that is avoiding astroids that get bigger(ants) but when you move your ship(shoe) stays in the same place and the astroids(ants) move. The ants/astroids also get bigger like you are going close to them.

Comment: What's wrong in your code?

Comment: You should post your relevant code here. If your link disappears, this question is useless.

Comment: What about it isn't working? Just posting a comment, because it won't let you post a link with code is not posting code. It expects code for a reason.

Comment: the canvas does not show up @bic

Comment: Your question seriously lacks information necessary to help. Please revise your question.

Comment: @kuma I dont know what is wrong that is why I posted it.

Comment: @tylerH that is why I posted it, I don't know.

Comment: We don't even know the desired outcome. Plus you need to put some code in your question.

Comment: Try posting your full JavaScript code on the Code Review sister site

Comment: Use the browser console to get Javascript errors. You can get it in alot of browsers by pressing F12.

Comment: Or, if you are using JSFiddle, then use the JSHint button.

Comment: You have syntax errors that need fixing before the script will run,  Use JSHint to locate and correct them, then see if your page runs better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var ship = {
    speed: 256; 
};
```

Remove the `;` after the value.

```
if astroid.width < 200{
```

and

```
if astroid.width > 200{
```

Need parentheses around the `if` conditions.

The error console is helpful! But now it's just stuck in an infinite loop of `monsterImage is not defined`. Just... go back, write your code *more carefully*, and **use the error console**! It's there for a reason!

Comment: You are defining `astroidImage` (spelled wrong, btw) but trying to use `monsterImage`.